# Visa refusal. Should I reapply or appeal?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My visa got rejected because I've shown **wrong income**, it was to be **shown in currency I'm earning but I showed it in Pounds**. I wrote I have nobody staying in UK but in addition I wrote to meet my cousin sister, but she is not my real sister or close one. Is it necessary to mention her details?

Should I appeal with the documents again or should I reapply?

Comment: If you reapply you will only confirm their suspicions of you being a liar, appealing seems more appropriate IMO since it will be more like clearing some points you missed during the first application.

Comment: They would have mentioned if you could appeal or not ? Secondly which visa did you apply for, generally they have columns for currency you earned in and converted to pounds. If your sister(so called) isn't sponsoring you or you aren't going to stay with her, leave her out or it will complicate things further.

Comment: No. They are not going to refuse a visa over someone showing income denominated in Sterling.  Perhaps you have misunderstood what they wrote.  Would you please edit your question to include the EXACT text in your refusal notice?  Something doesn't make sense!

Comment: @MeNoTalk, there's no appeal available for visitors

Comment: What's a 'cousin sister'? Surely your sister's cousin is also a cousin, and indeed a relative?

Comment: @MarkMayo, 'cousin-sister' is Pakistani for 1st cousin female.  Of course in Appalachia, the meaning is literal :)

Comment: @GayotFow today I learned!

Comment: Why is this being upvoted??? Burning a CLOSE flag on this one. There's no such requirement as '...it was to be shown in currency I'm earning...' Did you look at the form?